I encountered a technical difficulty and needed to use J/XFS technology to operate the printer function
Currently I found a J/XFS printer demo, but I can't run it. I would like to ask for help. Thank you.
I tried to start the server service, but the configuration was missing and could not be started.I would like a document for configuring a startup service
